# Interest rates are an example of a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

In this example, you deposit `$1,000` in a
CD at your local bank, it earns `6%` annual interest compounded monthly. What is the balance at
the end of `12 months`? (hint: don’t forget to find the monthly interest rate)

My answer is $1063.402318714$, the right answer is $1061.68$. Which answer is right?
[image]

Comment: The right answer is right. How did you get yours?

Comment: The usual computation would be $1000\times \left(1+\frac {.06}{12} \right)^{12}$ which yields the "right answer".  What calculation did you do?

Comment: @lulu, I updated the question

Comment: @lulu, but I don't get it, why my solution does not work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the question is incorrectly stated. An *annual* interest rate of $6\%$ yields $6\%$ after *twelve months* !

If you consider that it was obtained by compounding monthly, the monthly interest rate must have been $100(\sqrt[12]{1.06}-1)\approx0.487\%$, which of course restores $6\%$ in twelve months by $100(1.0049^{12}-1)$.

A better phrased statement would be about a monthly interest rate that woulds yield $6\%$ yearly if *not* compounded, hence $0.5\%$ monthly. Then compounded on twelve months, $100(1.005^12-1)\approx6.17\%$.

Comment: Money jargon doesn't *have* to make math sense ;-) See [nominal vs. effective interest rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_interest_rate#Nominal_versus_effective_interest_rate) for example.

Comment: @dxiv: not using the proper jargon indeed made the question incorrect.